# How to confirm alert popup with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm clicking on a link that contains a confirm dialog but not being able to dismiss.

I tried to press "Enter" and use puppeteer's method to dismiss & accept the dialog but nothing happened.

The link:

```html
<a onclick="return confirm('Yes?');" id="link" href="google.com">
```

I tried:

```js
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log('here'); //does not pass
    await dialog.accept();
    //await dialog.dismiss();
});
```

and

```js
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

Comment: Are you attaching to that event before clicking the link?

Comment: Not sure I followed.. attaching how?

Comment: Are you calling `page.on` before clicking the link?

Comment: I wasn't, didn't know about that. It worked haha. You want to put this as an answer so i can accept? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you start listening to the `dialog` event **before** clicking the link. Something like this:

```js
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
  console.log('here');
  await dialog.accept();
});

await page.click('a');
```